# Python searching directory, list basename of file, no extension

Tags: python, file, printing, directory

I was wondering if there was anyway I could modify my code to only post the basename of the file, instead of the entire file including the extension.. I'm new to python, so I don't know much, and I don't want to modify something and have it completely break.

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir( "C:/headers" )

txt = open( 'C:/files.txt', 'w' )

for file in glob.glob( "*.h" ):
    with open( file ) as f:
        contents = f.read()
        if 'struct' in contents:
            txt.write( "%s\n"%file )
txt.close()
```

Basically, what it does is search through a directory of header files, and if it has the struct string in the file, it'll print the files in a txt file. However, when I run it, the txt file opens with all the files listed, but I want it to only list the basename of the file, I don't need the .h at the end of it.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

```
import glob
import os
import re
os.chdir( "C:/headers" )

txt = open( 'C:/files.txt', 'w' )

for file in glob.glob( "*.h" ):
    with open( file ) as f:
        contents = f.read()    [...]
        if 'struct' in contents:
            txt.write( "%s\n"% re.sub('\.h$', '', file) )
txt.close()
```

Good luck!

Comment: @chakolatemilk -- You have the power to delete comments (I can't tell you how many incorrect comments I've deleted).  Just click the little grey "x" that shows up when you move your cursor over your comment (it'll turn red when your cursor is on it) and it'll go away -- Nobody (other than moderators) will be able to see your silly mistakes :)

Answer (score 3):

```
root, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
name = os.path.basename(root)
```

`root` will contain the entire path of the given file name up to where the period would be before the extension, `name` will only be the name of the file without the leading path.

Answer (score 0):

Simply in one line..., returns the found files without any file extension, for the files found in the given search directory with the requested file extension...!

```
Found_BaseFile_Names= [(f.split('.'))[0] for f in os.listdir(SearchDir) if f.endswith('.txt')]
```